# tvOS: Collectionview is not showing data from the REST API response?

Tags: xamarin, uicollectionview, tvos

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/tvos/user-interface/collection-views?tabs=macos) blog for implementing the `Collectionview` in my tvOS application. In this blog the data is adding on the `CityViewDatasource` class. Static datas are added on this blog like below:

```
        Cities.Clear();
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City01.jpg", "Houses by Water", false));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City02.jpg", "Turning Circle", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City03.jpg", "Skyline at Night", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City04.jpg", "Golden Gate Bridge", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City05.jpg", "Roads by Night", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City06.jpg", "Church Domes", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City07.jpg", "Mountain Lights", true));
        Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City08.jpg", "City Scene", false));
```

I need to change the static data into dynamic by calling a REST API like below:

```
 try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("My REST API");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Response.ToString()))
                {
                    var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoList>(Response.ToString());
                    Cities.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < category.webContentHBList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Cities.Add(new CityInfo(category.webContentHBList[i].ImageUrl, category.webContentHBList[i].title, true));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("exception:>>" + e);
        }
```

But when I run the project no data is coming on the UI, only a blank screen is showing. No errors are showing in the output window.

I have included the service domains on the info.plist under `NSAppTransportSecurity`. The REST API calling is success and I able to get the count of items. I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XB8zDh_JEMeOSv59Lu8C3_sfLBLeOTZO/view?usp=sharing) for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check the shared code and project ,you need to `ReloadData` after receiving
api data and dealing with them .

Modify as follow :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("REST API");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Response.ToString()))
    {
        var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoList>(Response.ToString());
        Cities.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < category.webContentHBList.Count; i++)
        {
            //Cities.Add(new CityInfo("category.webContentHBList[i].thumbnailImageUrl.Replace(" ","%20"), category.webContentHBList[i].pageTitle, true));
            Cities.Add(new CityInfo("City01.jpg", category.webContentHBList[i].pageTitle, true));
                        
        }
        // reload data after receiving 
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            // manipulate UI controls
            this.ViewController.ReloadData();
        });
    }
}
```

=======================Update=================================

If want to show url image :

```
Cities.Add(new CityInfo(category.webContentHBList[i].thumbnailImageUrl, category.webContentHBList[i].pageTitle, true));
```

You can modify `CityCollectionViewCell.cs` as follow :

```
...

public CityInfo City {
    get { return _city; }
    set {
        _city = value;
        //CityView.Image = UIImage.FromFile (City.ImageFilename);
        CityView.Image = FromUrl(City.ImageFilename);
        // here api url not showing , it's invalid in tvOS 
        // such as using test url , it will show 
        // CityView.Image = FromUrl(https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/06/30/N5sh5R.png)
        CityView.Alpha = (City.CanSelect) ? 1.0f : 0.5f;
        CityTitle.Text = City.Title;
    }
}
#endregion

static UIImage FromUrl(string uri)
{
    using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
    using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
        return UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
}

...
```

Comment: Could you please see the commented first line inside the for loop. I need to use that line instead of second line, the items have image url and I need to show that particular image on the UI. I uncomment that line now, but image part is blank. Is there any other addition for loading the image via a URL?

Comment: @SreejithSree Hi , the dynamic images means the image like a gif ?

Comment: There is an imageurl in the response, we need to add the rooturl for getting the complete image, if you check the commented line you can see a root url + the image remaining url.I need to show that image on the UI(not gif only image), sample image url: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/catholic-brain/prod/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2020/04/01/06/59/24/050/head/who-made-the-world-thumbnail%20v2-thumbnail.png

Comment: @SreejithSree Got it , you modify `CityCollectionViewCell.cs` file add method for showing url image . Then it will shows .

Comment: @SreejithSree I have updated answer . However , using your api image url not works , because `NSUrl` will throw (return nil in ObjC) then the provided URL is invalid (not RFC 2396 compliant). See Apple's documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString . You can use another image url to check this method , it will work .(Such as : https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/06/30/N5sh5R.png)

Comment: @SreejithSree Have approved . I have checked that the image url , found that the reason should be the `space` character . It contains inside the image name , such as the first url image is : `who-made-the-world-thumbnail v2-thumbnail.png` . You will see that it coantins the ` ` , and apple will deal with this url with space character .

Comment: @SreejithSree In browser of PC , this space will be converted to  `%20` , such as : who-`made-the-world-thumbnail%20v2-thumbnail.png` , however applce can not deal with that . So it will not show .

Comment: I have solved that issue by replacing the blank space with %20, now I am able to view my images on the UI. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zPS91TvmHDoPA-sCGKmesRsxThk_Zxpo/view?usp=sharing Thank you very much